# Characterisation of open mappings

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X, Y$ be normed spaces and $F$ - linear continuous mapping.

Is it true that $F:X\rightarrow Y$ is open, $\iff F(B(0,\epsilon))$ is open for any $B(0,\epsilon)$ denoting an open ball with radius $\epsilon$.

I think its true. Can anyone verify this?

Comment: Yes, it's true. Have you an idea how to prove it?

Comment: Is it also true that I can replace right-hand side with "there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $B(0,\delta)\subset F(B(0,\epsilon))$"

Comment: Yes, that is also true. Even $\bigl(F(B(0,1)\bigr)^{\Large\circ} \neq \varnothing$ suffices.

Comment: So it should be "$\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta>0 \dots$ " yes?

Comment: Can we remove one assumption (about continuity of F)?

Comment: Yes, the continuity is not needed.

Comment: In both cases??

Comment: Let $X,Y$ be normed spaces, and $F \colon X\to Y$ linear. Then $F$ is open if and only if $\bigl(F(B(0,1)\bigr)^{\Large\circ} \neq\varnothing$.